# php8 - parallel - PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, parallel-processing

I am unable to make php_parallel ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/parallel.setup.php ) extension to work.

This is what I have done:

1. Downloaded PHP 8.1.7 64bit Thread Safe into "D:\PHP8TS"
2. Downloaded parallels 1.1.4 from "https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/parallel/1.1.4/php_parallel-1.1.4-7.4-ts-vc15-x64.zip"
3. Put file "pthreadVC2.dll" into "D:\PHP8TS"
4. Put file "php_parallel.dll" into "D:\PHP8TS\ext" dir
5. Put "extension=D:\PHP8TS\ext\php_parallel.dll" line into php.ini
6. Put "D:\PHP8TS\pthreadVC2.dll" into PATH environment variable
7. Execute "D:\PHP8TS\php.exe -v" with result:

   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\PHP8TS\ext\php_parallel.dll' (tried: D:\PHP8TS\ext\php_parallel.dll (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_D:\PHP8TS\ext\php_parallel.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

   Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\PHP8TS\ext\php_parallel.dll' (tried: D:\PHP8TS\ext\php_parallel.dll (The specified module could not be found), C:\php\ext\php_D:\PHP8TS\ext\php_parallel.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
   PHP 8.1.7 (cli) (built: Jun  7 2022 21:45:53) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
   Copyright (c) The PHP Group
   Zend Engine v4.1.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

What have I done wrong? Was anyone successful in running this extension on PHP 8.1.7?

By this way, I was sucessfully able to add other PHP extensions (for example pdo_sqlite).

Comment: In point 6 the PATH is missing an `l` at the end? I'm sure that's just a typo. But that's the first thing I would check for: Typos and capitalization.

Comment: Whoops yes, thanks, I had in wrong in environment path too. But fixing that haven't solved it. (tried restart too).

Other paths/capitalization are correct.

Comment: Since PHP is looking for `C:\php\ext\php_D:\PHP8TS\ext\php_parallel.dll.dll` I would try to place your DLL files into `C:\php\ext` and in ini file just put `extensions=parallel.dll` (or just `parallel`)

Comment: PHP is looking in the right location (it's saying "tried D:\PHP8TS\ext\php_parallel.dll"). The other location is just fallback location.  And If I try other extensions, for example "extension=D:\PHP8TS\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll", it's loading that correctly.

Comment: I'm just saying this, without any knowledge of this library, but could it be a permissions issue? This has often bugged me.

Comment: Permissions are fine. I have tried that with PHP 7.4.30 TS and it's working :( Which probably means the PHP8 is just not supported .. but according to https://github.com/krakjoe/parallel it should be ..

Comment: Ok, there are some issues regarding PHP 8.1+, so it's not yet fully supported https://github.com/krakjoe/parallel/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallel 1.1.4 is for PHP 7.2, 7.3, and 7.4.
Unfortunately you cannot use it for PHP8.0+.

You need to use Parallel 1.2.1. So far I haven't been able to find a compiled windows binary for this version though :(